tikz: Placing elements (from a list) in a circle, alternating between different groups
I would like to arrange a number of elements (nE, say, 12 people) in a circle (say, a round table). The elements cannot be generated algorithmically, but consist of text entries that need to be read from a list (say, names of people -- in contrast to this related case). Each element belongs to one of a number of groups (nG, say, 3 families). A rule requires that once an element from one group has been placed, one element each from all the other groups needs to be placed before the next element from the first group is placed (i.e. in this case that no two family members sit next to each other).
This is easily done the simple but tedious way by hand using plain tikz. Here's an example with six elements in two groups:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

% nE = 6
% nG = 2
% listG1 = {Capulet, Juliet, Tybalt}
% listG2 = {Montague, Romeo, Benvolio}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0: 5cm){Capulet};
\node at (60: 5cm){Montague};
\node at (120: 5cm){Juliet};
\node at (180: 5cm){Romeo};
\node at (240: 5cm){Tybalt};
\node at (300: 5cm){Benvolio};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It's obvious that this solution lacks any flexibility. As the number of entries to be arranged will change, the angles will need to change as well. And of course, there's no automatic processing of the list entries either.
How would one go about constructing an algorithm that distributes the elements automatically based on a given nE, nG, and the corresponding lists?
BTW: a slightly different, but related application would be only /one/ list of elements (nG = 1) with a given "spacing": after placing the first element at position 0°, move (360/nE)° further down the circle, and place the next element there, making as many rounds way past 1x360° as necessary.

Here's how I would phrase it in pseudo-code (maybe this helps to show that my problem may indeed be simpler that it seems):
NumberOfLists = 2
ItemsPerList = 3
Angle = 360 / (ItemsPerList*NumberOfLists)

List1 = {Item1.1, Item1.2, Item1.3}
List2 = {Item2.1, Item2.2, Item2.3}

FOR EACH x IN 1..ItemsPerList DO
DRAW Item1.x
ADVANCE-BY Angle
DRAW Item2.x
ADVANCE-BY Angle


How many names will you have in total? Is there something like circular layers?

How does your input look like? How do you want it to look like? Placing nodes in a circle isn't the problem.

@MS-SPO I'm not familiar with the term "circular layers" unfortunately, but regarding the number of items I'd say that the ideal answer to my question would be one that's agnostic to the number. But let's assume a number not higher than what a human can grasp on the resulting chart when output at reasonable size. Let's say: a few dozen?

@Qrrbrbirlbel I can give the input pretty much any format that a TeX/tikz-based solution requires. Let's assume: the input will have the format that needs the least hassle in the TeX code. As for what I want it to look like: here, too, there's nothing specific that I have in mind yet; it's simply not within the scope of my current problem. Giving it a certain look is a later step, and one that's usually within my skills. What's not so much within my skills at the moment is the part that, to you, isn't the problem: "placing nodes in a circle" [according to above specifications]. (-:

Circular layers: 6 names at the inner circle, referencing at least 26 at the next larger one, 2^26 on the next and so on. Think of an onion for the layers, which quickly becomes densly crowded.

@NilsL If I see this correctly, you have families F1 = {f11, f12, f13}, F2 = {f21, f22, f23} and F3 = {f31, f32, f33} and want these element to be placed in the order f11, f21, f31, f12, f22, f32, f13, f23, f33. Since you don't want to give these element in that order, we either need to place each family with enough room for the other families or process the lists parallelI (→ parallel foreach). A little bit math for the first or a bit of TeXing for the second …

A simple chain that evaluates the position for every family member given that the families are given in ordner.
If the families are F1 = {f11, f12, f13} and F2 = {f21, f22, f23}, you can feed to the chain the family members in the order f11, f12, f13, f21, f22, f23 and it will place them circular in the order f11, f21, f12, f22, f13, f23.
You will need to specify the number of families and the number of entries per family. The keys phase and radius can be used to customize the circle.
Really, all that is necessary is the placement
at = ({
   \tfvo{phase}
 + mod(#1,\tfvo{entries}) * 360 / (\tfvo{entries})
 + int(#1/(\tfvo{entries})) * 360 / (\tfvo{entries}) / (\tfvo{families})
}:{
  \tfvo{radius}
})

where #1 is the number of node starting at 0 (and not 1 as the chains library does).
but separately calculating the counter values \tikzfamcounter and \tikzfammembercounter allows us to set styles depending on the family number, the member number and more.
This is used in the second example.
The first example is using its own loop over the families.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newcommand*\tikzfamset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/fam}}
\newcommand*\tfvo[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fam/#1}}
\tikzfamset{
  .code=\tikzfamset{#1},
  families/.initial=0, entries/.initial=0, % per family
  phase/.initial=0, radius/.initial=3,
  calc/.code=%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikzfamcounter{int(#1/(\tfvo{entries}))}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikzfammembercounter{mod(#1,\tfvo{entries})}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tikzfamangle{\tfvo{phase}+\tikzfammembercounter*360/(\tfvo{entries})
                                 +\tikzfamcounter*360/(\tfvo{entries})/(\tfvo{families})},
  at/.style={
    fam/calc={#1},
    at={(\tikzfamangle:{\tfvo{radius}})},
    fam/every \tikzfamcounter\space family/.try,                                   % every ith family is stylable
    fam/every \tikzfammembercounter\space member/.try,                             % every jth member is stylable
    fam/family member \tikzfamcounter-\tikzfammembercounter/.try,                  % every member i-j is stylable
    fam/every family member/.try/.expanded={\tikzfamcounter}{\tikzfammembercounter}% every member is styleable
  },
  start/.style={/tikz/start chain=#1placed {fam/at=\pgfinteval{\tikzchaincount-1}}}, start/.default=,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  fam={families=2, entries=3, start},
  fam cap/.style=red,
  fam mon/.style=blue]
\foreach \fam/\members in {
  cap/{Capulet, Juliet, Tybalt},
  mon/{Montague, Romeo, Benvolio}}
  \foreach \member in \members
    \node[on chain, fam \fam]{\member};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  fam={
    phase=90, radius=2, families=3, entries=3, start,
    every family member/.style 2 args={label={[scale=.5]above:#1-#2}},
    every 0 family/.style=red,
    every 1 family/.style=green,
    every 2 family/.style=blue,
    every 0 member/.style={fill=red!10},
    every 1 member/.style={fill=green!10},
    every 2 member/.style={fill=blue!10},
  },
  every on chain/.style={above, rotate=\tikzfamangle-90, draw},
]
\draw[->] (90:1.9) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=360*8/9, radius=1.9];

\node[on chain]{Foo};
\node[on chain]{Bar};
\node[on chain]{Foobar};

\node[on chain]{$x_1$};
\node[on chain]{$x_2$};
\node[on chain]{$x_3$};

\node[on chain]{\TeX};
\node[on chain]{\LaTeX};
\node[on chain]{Ti\textit kZ};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output



Clockwise needs some minus signs …
